I cannot send voice memos that have been transferred from an android to apple
More than a year ago I transferred all my data from an android to an IPhone 14 but recently I got an IPhone 15 pro and upgraded it to IOS 18 and I went back to my old recordings from android and I indeed can play them on my voice memos app but I cannot send then anywhere because apparently they do not exist, when I try to send them through IMessage, it takes me to the conversation but there is nothing attached, same with email, nothing attached, same with notes, I click share but the note is empty , when I tried to send it through telegram the share page disappeared as if it has shared but it did not, nothing was shared, when I tried through WhatsApp then it shows my a black screen, as if like a black photo trying to be sent but I cannot even send it because nothing happens when I click the WhatsApp share button, I tried saving it to files and the page of sharing disappears but it saves nothing, when trying to airdrop, it doesn’t even show the file trying to be shared, it just says failed or says waiting for eternity and lastly when I tried to copy the link it doesn’t paste anything because it didn’t copy anything since the file apparently doesn’t exist so it seems like the recording is on my phone but the file literally do not exist and I’ve searched for an answer but no one ever talked about something like this so I wonder if there is literally anything I can do because I think I have tried everything like duplicating it etc. Like please help me out if that’s possible, thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should reach out to Apple Support. This sounds like an error with the migration process that will require a bug fix to correct.
There's a chance somebody here will have seen this and has a solution, but unless that's the case then Apple Support is your best opportunity.

The app iMazing claims to be able to transfer voice memos. I would recommend downloading it and trying to retrieve them this way.
I have not tested whether this will work, so if there is no trial available then proceed at your own risk.
